# How to use MPMoviePlayerViewController on iOS4(3.1.3 update)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

My iPhone is a iOS4(3.1.3 update).
I tryid this code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
}

@end
//-------------------------------------------------
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "testViewController.h"

@implementation testViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSBundle *Bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *moviePath = [Bundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"MOV"];
  NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];

  MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]; 
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
  theMovie.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [theMovie.moviePlayer play];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

when I run the aplication the video didn't work just only plays sound.
What is wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem in my app. [Here is a link to my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092117/a-problem-with-media-player-base-on-ios4-and-deploy-ios3/3116123#3116123).

Answer (score 2):

just add below source to code:-

```
[themovie.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  

[self.view addSubview:themovie.view];
```

Then it will worked sure......