# Video with iPhone 3.0 OS application getting crash while running in iphone 4.0 OS

Tags: iphone, video, operating-system, mpmovieplayercontroller, iphone-4

I am having a crash issue while playing video in iphone 4.0 OS. Actually, I have created application with base SDK 3.0 and now i am just installing application to 4.0 OS device.

It is not working in that... I have debugged that issue and found that in 4.0 OS, apple change the framework and methods to play the video.

Any one help me how to overcome this issue.

Here is my code which is running fine in 3.0 OS.

```
-(void)play
    {
     NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
     //NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Icon" ofType:@"png"];
     NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"loader" ofType:@"m4v"];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
     moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
     moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                  object:moviePlayer];
     moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
     [moviePlayer play];
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Pragnesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS4, you need to use the MPMoviePlayerViewController. I posted my [working code sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092117/a-problem-with-media-player-base-on-ios4-and-deploy-ios3/3116123#3116123).

Comment: Ya i understand but my base sdk is 3.1.2 then compiler is giving error for MPMoviePlayerViewController..

Comment: To become compatible with iOS4, you will need to upgrade your xcode to 3.2.3, set your base SDK to 4.0 and then set your target OS to 3.0. Then the code snippet should work and you should be 4.0 and 3.0 compatible. The MPMoviePlayerViewController is only available in the 4.0 SDK. Lastly, Apple is wanting everyone to upgrade their apps to the 4.0 SDK and that is part od the way you get the "tested on iOS4" label in the AppStore.